# Is there a hotkey to gain a point in a skill without clicking the icon?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was watching a video on YouTube this morning and it seemed that the player was able to spend his skill points without actually moving his mouse to the little icons and clicking.  In DotA it was definitely possible using the hotkeys, but does League of Legends support something like this?

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select which skill to level up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while hitting the hotkey for that skill to level it up.

Comment: While also on the subject of hotkeys without mice, if you have a targetted ability that can target yourself, you can hold down `Alt` when hitting the hotkey to automatically target yourself.

Comment: Wow I would never have even thought to ask about a feature like that but that's awesome.

Comment: @Strix I didn't, either, until I saw my brother rapidly hasting himself and using his Ult with Zilean last week, and so I asked him what he was doing. Unfortunately, I get no mileage out of it yet since none of my champions actually have such abilities. But it's definitely a very neat trick.

Comment: And finally you can use `shift` + an ability to "smartcast" which means instantly using the ability at the target of the cursor, bypassing the targeting UI that normally happens when you click a skill.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the hotkey commands by highlighting the box under 'Secondary' and clicking the key you want to use. I like it a lot better than using shift or ctrl because it's a lot faster.

Example - Quite often in mid lane whoever reaches level 6 first and engages will most likely win. Therefore, I can set the level up 'R' skill as the A key or something to level it up quicker instead of having to click Ctrl-R.

It's very useful and has gotten me many kills.

In addition, I do not Shift-QWER to smartcast. I change the smartcast hotkeys directly to Q/W/E/R on certain champions who utilize smartcast well (Usually Bursters) such as Leblanc and Talon.